# Proof on exponential Relation R

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations

Prove that $(R^a)^b = R^{ab}$ for any integers $a,b >= 1$.

A handy fact: The connectivity relation $R^*$ consists of the pairs $(x, y)$ such that there is a path of length at least $1$ from $x$ to $y$ in $R$. Because $R^n$ consists of the pairs $(x, y)$ such that there is a path of length $n$ from $x$ to $y$, it follows that $R^*$ is the union of all the sets $R^n$.

Update: Upon further thought, I think this is a proof to be completed using mathematical induction.
The basis step would be $(R^1)^1$ to get $R^{1*1}$ which are both R, hence true.
Would the induction step be to prove $(R^2)^2$

Comment: It follows that **$R$** is the union of all the $R^n$? That's true only if $R$ is transitive. Perhaps you mean the transitive closure $R^+$ of $R$ is equal to the union. E.g. Suppose R is the set of pairs $(n,n+1)$ for $n\in \Bbb N$; then $R^+ = <$. // What you said is correct about how to prove $(R^a)^b = R^{ab}$. However, I don't see how this result about exponents helps you prove... whatever it is you're trying to prove in the last sentence.

Comment: you're right - i have updated the question to be more relevant. thank you.

Comment: OK... but now, um, no: it's really a double induction. For each $a$, you want to show that $(R^a)^n = R^{an}$. The basis step is the same as what you have. The IH is $(R^a)^n = R^{an}$, and you want to prove that $(R^a)^{(n+1)} = R^{a(n+1)}$. You have a recursive/inductive definition of the powers of *any* relation, right? not just this $R$. So in particular that definition applies to $R^a$ too. Part of the proof will be to rephrase this in terms of your "connectivity" notion, which you obliterated;), namely that $S^n$ is all $(x,y)$ s.t. there's a path $x=x_1 S x_2 S\dotsc Sx_n=y$.

Comment: working on the proof by induction, it seems that this can be proven using properties of exponents alone. Would that not suffice? I am trying to understand how the connectivity notion comes into play.

Comment: Let's work it out: $(R^a)^{n+1} = (R^a)^n R^a = \text{ [by IH] } R^{an} R^a  = \text{(I'm guessing you know $R^i R^j = R^{i+j}$) } R^{an + a} = R^{a(n+1)}$. So, no, the connectivity notion doesn't come into play *directly*, but perhaps it does in proving that $R^i R^j = R^{i+j}$ for all $i,j$.

Comment: There is a reason I changed your variables $a,b$ to $x,y$ in the statement "The connectivity relation $R^*$ consists of the pairs $(a, b)$ such that there is a path of length at least $1$ from $a$ to $b$ in R." You changed it back to that misleading/confusing form; I changed it back again. **I won't correct it a third time**. $x,y$ are things related by $R$; $a,b$ are integers; they have nothing to do with each other, and $a,b$ are already in play.